# Got an assignment stuck don't know why it is not working?

Tags: java, string

Hi there I am new to java, studying in my bs course from a couple of weeks. So please don't mind if I ask something stupid. btw coming to the point. Assignment was that you have to write a program in which I have to break the email address into parts using StringBuffer
e.g:
if the given email is hassanaqve@gmail.com so I have to break it like
username: hassanaqve
domain name : gmail
extension : .com

I tried myself but it is not working there are no errors but also not giving output

```
    import java.lang.*;
public class Lab5 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringBuffer email = new StringBuffer ("Hassanaqve@gmail.com");
         for ( int i=0; i<= email.length(); i++){
             if ( email.substring (i).equals ("@")){
                 System.out.println( "Username : " + email.substring(0,i));
                 int j=i;
                 for ( int p=0; j<= email.length(); p++ ){
                   if ( email.substring (p) == (".")){
                       System.out.println( "doamin : " + email.substring(j,p));
                       System.out.println( "extention : " + email.substring(p+1,p+4));
                   }  
                 }

             }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Why use a for loop? Also you're not using substring correctly. When you give it a single parameter, it will return the sub String from the index to the end of the String.

Comment: I tried everything but it is not working ! please explain it

Comment: I rollback your edit that add solution in the question, if you would like to post a solution, it is better to post it as an answer..

Answer (score 1):

emailString.subString(0,emailString.indexOf('@')) will give you username

emailString.subString(emailString.lastIndexOf('.')) will give extention

emailString.subString(0,emailString.indexOf('@')+1,emailString.lastIndexOf('.')) will give you domsin name